# WMS - Export Retrieved XML Data

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms

I use WMS layer in my app and could successfully retrieved Feature Info by click like so: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html

My question is: Is there any way to export the retrieved data in separate variables? So that I can organize the popup instead id this table. I see that its an XML file but still can't find a way to handle it.